# How do I adjust layout elements for different screen densities?

Tags: android

Let's say I have an ImageButton in my app. The size of the .png for ImageButton is 50x50px and it was originally designed for xhdpi. Let's say I now want to adjust this .png image for other screen densities. Is there some kind of formula that helps you calculate what would be the best size of the image to suit a certain density? I really doubt trying random width and heights is the way to go.

I did some research and found this image:

[image]

My basic understanding of maths tells me that I should originally design it for mdpi and then just multiply or divide it to get hdpi/xhdpi/ldpi, is that the right way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you found here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and the formula is 100% correct, the standard is to use 96*96 for xhdpi 72*72 for hdpi 48*48 for mdpi and 32*32 for ldpi but since you didn't follow standard size you can still follow this formula.

Take standard sizes as example on this formula

```
48*1 = 48 which is mdpi
48*.75 = 32 which is ldpi
48*1.5 = 72 which is hdpi
48*2 = 96 which is xhdpi
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool for re-sizing images. You just need to provide the xhdpi and the tool will scale down the images to different densities. https://code.google.com/p/9patch-resizer/